# Why do I get a conflicting implementations error when specializing a trait?

Tags: rust

I'm not sure that I understand why this code won't compile. It seems like the new "vector" `Mul` specialization is more specific than the default one, and I don't *think* that I'm relying on the `Vectorizable` trait not having been defined for a type external to my crate.

```
#![feature(cfg_target_feature)]
#![feature(specialization)]

use std::marker::PhantomData;
use std::ops::{Mul, Add};

type Dimension = (usize, usize);
type Coordinate = (usize, usize);

pub trait Ordering {
    // omitted
}

pub struct RowMajor {}
impl Ordering for RowMajor {}

pub struct ColumnMajor {}
impl Ordering for ColumnMajor {}

// NxM matrix
pub struct Matrix<T, O: Ordering> {
    dim: Dimension,
    values: Vec<T>,

    // needed so that we can add type bound to struct
    ordering: PhantomData<O>,
}

trait VectorSize {}

struct V4x {}
impl VectorSize for V4x {}
// others defined for other sizes

trait Vectorizable {
    type SimdType; /*: simd::Simd */
    type VectorSize: VectorSize;
}

#[cfg(target_feature = "sse")]
impl Vectorizable for f32 {
    type SimdType = f32; /* simd::f32x4 */
    type VectorSize = V4x;
}

impl<'a, 'b, T1, T2, O1: Ordering, O2: Ordering>
    Mul<&'b Matrix<T2, O2>> for &'a Matrix<T1, O1>
where
    T1: Mul<T2> + Clone,
    T2: Clone,
    <T1 as Mul<T2>>::Output: Add<Output = <T1 as Mul<T2>>::Output> + Clone + Default,
{
// always output row major because we compute in row major order
    type Output = Matrix<
        <T1 as Mul<T2>>::Output
        , RowMajor>;

// self is a &'a
    default fn mul(self, rhs: &'b Matrix<T2, O2>) -> Self::Output
    {
        unimplemented!();
    }
}

impl<'a, 'b, T: Vectorizable> Mul<&'b Matrix<T, ColumnMajor>> for &'a Matrix<T, RowMajor> {
    fn mul(self, rhs: &'b Matrix<T, ColumnMajor>) -> Self::Output {
        unimplemented!();
    }
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f373ba95e1e4e6af0ef4bbf954d224d0&version=nightly))

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `std::ops::Mul<&Matrix<_, ColumnMajor>>` for type `&Matrix<_, RowMajor>`:
  --> src/main.rs:65:1
   |
46 | / impl<'a, 'b, T1, T2, O1: Ordering, O2: Ordering>
47 | |     Mul<&'b Matrix<T2, O2>> for &'a Matrix<T1, O1>
48 | | where
49 | |     T1: Mul<T2> + Clone,
...  |
62 | |     }
63 | | }
   | |_- first implementation here
64 | 
65 | / impl<'a, 'b, T: Vectorizable> Mul<&'b Matrix<T, ColumnMajor>> for &'a Matrix<T, RowMajor> {
66 | |     fn mul(self, rhs: &'b Matrix<T, ColumnMajor>) -> Self::Output {
67 | |         unimplemented!();
68 | |     }
69 | | }
   | |_^ conflicting implementation for `&Matrix<_, RowMajor>`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Vectorizable` implementation is *not* more specific, for instance it does not mention anything about `T * T` being a valid operation, required by the general one.

You need to add more bounds to the `Vectorizable` impl to match the general one:

```
impl<'a, 'b, T> Mul<&'b Matrix<T, ColumnMajor>> for &'a Matrix<T, RowMajor> 
where
    T: Vectorizable + Mul + Clone,
    T::Output: Add<Output = T::Output> + Clone + Default,
{
```

Alternatively, you could add those bounds as the supertrait of `Vectorizable`:

```
trait Vectorizable: Mul<Output=Self> + Add<Output = Self> + Clone + Default {
    // ...
}

impl<'a, 'b, T: Vectorizable> Mul<&'b Matrix<T, ColumnMajor>> for &'a Matrix<T, RowMajor> {
    // ...
}
```