# Why isn't `From` automatically used for coercing to trait implementing type

Tags: generics, rust, polymorphism, implicit-conversion

I have two traits:

```
trait Foo {}
trait Bar {}

struct FooImpl;
impl Foo for FooImpl {}

struct BarImpl;
impl Bar for BarImpl {}
```

And a third type I want to convert into:

```
struct Baz;

trait IntoBaz {
    fn into(self) -> Baz;
}
```

I can't define two `impl`s of `IntoBaz` for the two traits because of coherence, so I wrap one instead:

```
struct FooWrapper<F>(F)
where
    F: Sized;

impl<F: Foo + Sized> From<F> for FooWrapper<F> {
    fn from(f: F) -> FooWrapper<F> {
        FooWrapper(f)
    }
}

impl<F: Foo + Sized> IntoBaz for FooWrapper<F> {
    fn into(self) -> Baz {
        Baz
    }
}
```

And I don't wrap the other:

```
impl<B: Bar> IntoBaz for B {
    fn into(self) -> Baz {
        Baz
    }
}

fn do_thing<B: IntoBaz>(b: &B) {}

fn main() {
    do_thing(&BarImpl);
}
```

So far so good, but why doesn't this line work?

```
fn main() {
    do_thing(&FooImpl);
}
```

## Motivation

I'm trying to add `io::Write` support to a library with `fmt::Write` support without introducing a breaking change.

The easiest way would be to define some internal `Write` trait which covers the shared behaviour, but the coherence problem means I can't just write `From<io::Write>` instances to the internal trait.

I've tried wrapping `io::Write` instances, to make the coercion explicit so the compiler prioritises the shorter path and avoids the incoherence, but it won't auto-coerce using the `From` instance.

Comment: The error  says that `FooImpl` doesn't implement `Bar` (which is required for your blanket impl of `IntoBaz`). Didn't you intend to do: `do_thing(&FooWrapper(FooImpl));` ?

Comment: No, because the goal is having the auto-coercion do that - I don't understand why, in this case, it doesn't.

Comment: `from()` or `into()` don't just get automagically called. You would need to do something like: `do_thing(&FooWrapper::from(FooImpl));`

Comment: The only reasonable way of getting a user-defined automatic coercion is to implement `Deref` on some wrapper type, which will cause the wrapper to automatically decay to the wrapped type.  You can see the [full list of coercions in th Nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/coercions.html).

Comment: `from()` is sometimes called automatically by the language - and I'm looking to avoid having to manually use the wrapper at the call site. It seems to me like there should be a way to use `From` or something similar to get around this coherence problem.

Comment: _"`from()` is sometimes called automatically by the language"_ — It might appear to work with some libraries, but this is just those libraries requiring the argument to be `Into<T>` and calling `.into()` explicitly, just like the body of `do_thing` would have to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the error message:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `FooImpl: Bar` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:48:5
   |
48 |     do_thing(&FooImpl);
   |     ^^^^^^^^ the trait `Bar` is not implemented for `FooImpl`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `IntoBaz` for `FooImpl`
note: required by `do_thing`
  --> src/main.rs:45:1
   |
45 | fn do_thing<B: IntoBaz>(b: &B) {}
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It's saying that `FooImpl` doesn't have an implementation of `Bar`, which is a requirement of your blanket `IntoBaz for B` implementation.

The `FooWrapper` implementation is not relevant because `FooImpl` is not the same as `FooWrapper`. The `From` and `Into` traits provide a way to convert between types, but it doesn't happen automatically.

You might try adding an implementation for things that can be converted into `FooWrapper`, but this won't work because the implementations could overlap (and [specialization](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1210-impl-specialization.md) is not stable yet).

But you can define an `IntoBaz` implementation for just `FooImpl`:

```
impl IntoBaz for FooImpl {
    fn into(self) -> Baz {
        IntoBaz::into(FooWrapper::from(self))
    }
}
```

Which will make your code compile:

```
fn main() {
    do_thing(&BarImpl);
    do_thing(&FooImpl);
}
```

Comment: I could do that for `FooImpl`, but it wouldn't solve the general problem I explain in the motivation, which needs the equivalent of two blanket-`impl`s. I'm trying to avoid the overlap by having the type-checker pick the instance (basically by shortest coercion distance to the target type).

Answer (score 3):

[PeterHall's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52689555/3650362) is completely correct about the question as asked. `From` and `Into` don't mean anything special on the type level.

However, you might just have asked the question too narrowly. It looks like you want `do_thing(&BarImpl)` and `do_thing(&FooImpl)` to compile and do the "right" things. If that's all you need, there is a somewhat tricky alternative approach that could work: add a type parameter to `IntoBaz` and use different types to make the `impl`s non-overlapping.

```
trait IntoBaz<T> {
    fn into_baz(self) -> Baz;
}

struct ByFoo;
impl<F: Foo> IntoBaz<ByFoo> for F {
    fn into_baz(self) -> Baz {
        Baz
    }
}

struct ByBar;
impl<B: Bar> IntoBaz<ByBar> for B {
    fn into_baz(self) -> Baz {
        Baz
    }
}
```

`do_thing` can now be generic over `T`:

```
fn do_thing<T, B: IntoBaz<T>>(_: &B) {}
```

When you call it, if there is only one `T` that works, the compiler will find it automatically.

```
fn main() {
    do_thing(&BarImpl);
    do_thing(&FooImpl);
}
```

---

> I'm trying to add `io::Write` support to a library with `fmt::Write` support without introducing a breaking change.

Unfortunately this suggestion is technically a breaking change. If there is some type that implements *both* `io::Write` and `fmt::Write`, then `do_thing(&implements_both)` (which used to use `fmt::Write`) will now fail to compile due to ambiguity. But any place where the choice of trait is unambiguous will still compile as it did before, so the risk of breakage is much lower.

#### See also:

- [Can I avoid eager ambiguity resolution for trait implementations with generics?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52281091/3650362)

Comment: Thanks for an interesting suggestion. I tried a similar approach, but using an `B: Into<I>` followed by a custom `I: IntoBaz`, but the type-checker doesn't use the orphan rule in type inference, so it unfortunately didn't work.

Of course, this is just a lot of grief to try to avoid writing `<method_name>_io`, so I'll probably just end up doing that instead.