# Strategies for resolving conflicting trait implementations when using generics in Rust?

Tags: rust, traits

What are some general strategies for resolving trait implementations when using generics in Rust?  As a contrived example, consider the following code that allows conversion from primitive types to a struct:

```rust
// External libraries
use std::fmt::Debug;

// Create some structure that we can convert from and into
#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyStruct <T> {
    val : T,
}

// Convert from a value
trait ConvertFrom <T>
where
    Self : Sized
{
    fn from(t : T) ->  Self;
}

// Convert T into a T
impl <T> ConvertFrom <T> for T {
    fn from(t : T) -> Self {
        t
    }
}

// Convert f32 into f64
impl ConvertFrom <f32> for f64 {
    fn from(t : f32) -> Self {
        t as f64 
    }
}

// Convert T into a MyStruct <U>
impl <T,U> ConvertFrom <T> for MyStruct <U>  
where
    U : ConvertFrom <T>
{
    fn from(t : T) -> Self {
        MyStruct{ val : ConvertFrom::<T>::from(t) }
    }
}  

// Test our conversion
fn foo01 <T> () -> ()
where
    T : ConvertFrom <f32> + Debug
{
    let y01 : T = ConvertFrom::<f32>::from(1.2_f32);
    println!("{:?}",y01);
}

fn main() {
    foo01::<MyStruct<f32>>();  
    foo01::<f64>();
}
```

This gives the compiler error:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `ConvertFrom<MyStruct<_>>` for type `MyStruct<_>`:
  --> src/test03.rs:33:1
   |
19 |   impl <T> ConvertFrom <T> for T {
   |   ------------------------------ first implementation here
...
33 | / impl <T,U> ConvertFrom <T> for MyStruct <U>
34 | | where
35 | |     U : ConvertFrom <T>
36 | | {
...  |
39 | |     }
40 | | }
   | |_^ conflicting implementation for `MyStruct<_>`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0119`.
error: Could not compile `rust_from_to`
```

This makes sense, there's an ambiguity between the identity conversion from `T->T` and from `T->MyStruct <U>` since `T` could be something like `MyStruct<f32>` and `U` could be `f32`.  What's not clear to me is how to resolve it and `rustc --explain E0119` did not give great hints.  At issue is that I'd like to have a conversion function that converts `T` into `MyStruct <U>` whenever `T` converts to `U`.  I can make this work if `T=U` with the trait:

```rust
// Convert T into a MyStruct <T>
impl <T> ConvertFrom <T> for MyStruct <T> {
    fn from(t : T) -> Self {
        MyStruct{ val : t }                        
    }
}
```

but this is less general than I'd like.  Is there a general strategy for constructing such traits or functions?

Comment: You may find the [marker structs + extra parameter](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6a74e5d5a8133e478898dcedf0162b11) idea as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52692592/3650362) to be useful. Might that answer your question? There are definitely drawbacks, like the proliferation of generics.

Comment: AFAIK there is no simple solution today. [RFC 1210](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1210-impl-specialization.md) aims to solve this once it is implemented.

Comment: I don't believe specialization can fix this; you still have a coherence issue because any downstream can `struct Quux; impl ConvertFrom<MyStruct<Quux>> for Quux` and neither `impl` in the example is more specific.