# Is it possible to create a generic impl for a trait that works with all but one subset of types?

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I am trying to write a generic method that accepts a function that returns either a `Serialize` value or an `Arc<Serialize>` value. My solution is to create a trait to unwrap the `Arc` if needed and produce a reference to the underlying value:

```rust
use serde::Serialize;
use std::sync::Arc;

pub trait Unwrapper {
    type Inner: Serialize;

    fn unwrap(&self) -> &Self::Inner;
}

impl<T> Unwrapper for T
where
    T: Serialize,
{
    type Inner = T;
    fn unwrap(&self) -> &Self::Inner {
        self
    }
}

impl<T> Unwrapper for Arc<T>
where
    T: Serialize,
{
    type Inner = T;
    fn unwrap(&self) -> &Self::Inner {
        self
    }
}

fn use_processor<F, O>(processor: F)
where
    O: Unwrapper,
    F: Fn() -> O,
{
    // do something useful processor
}
```

I get a `E0119` error due to the potential that `Arc` may implement `Serialize` in the future, like if I enable the serde crate's feature to allow just that:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `Unwrapper` for type `std::sync::Arc<_>`:
  --> src/lib.rs:20:1
   |
10 | / impl<T> Unwrapper for T
11 | | where
12 | |     T: Serialize,
13 | | {
...  |
17 | |     }
18 | | }
   | |_- first implementation here
19 | 
20 | / impl<T> Unwrapper for Arc<T>
21 | | where
22 | |     T: Serialize,
23 | | {
...  |
27 | |     }
28 | | }
   | |_^ conflicting implementation for `std::sync::Arc<_>`
```

I don't want to do this as I only want to allow the `Arc` at the top level and not within the value (for the same reasons the feature is not on by default). Given this, Is there a way to disable my first `impl` only for an `Arc`? Or is there a better approach to the to problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I implement a trait I don't own for a type I don't own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413201/how-do-i-implement-a-trait-i-dont-own-for-a-type-i-dont-own)

Comment: The problem is I cannot create "more specialized" impl (the second one) for a trait that supersedes the more generic one (the first one), so that I can provide special handling for this one subset of types (Arc<T>)

Comment: Maybe look at specialisation https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1210-impl-specialization.md

Comment: Thanks, I think that is what I was looking for with this piece of code, but I guess it is still only available on nightly.

Comment: You might be able to use a trick like [autoref-based stable specialization](https://github.com/dtolnay/case-studies/blob/master/autoref-specialization/README.md) or [deferring trait method resolution to the call site using generics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52692592/3650362). [I tried the second technique](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ee85f5c5d98fc68d710433c159271e1f), but I don't know if it worked because [the playground uses Serde with the `rc` feature](https://github.com/integer32llc/rust-playground/blob/master/compiler/base/Cargo.toml#L838).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your attempt does not work because
it is not possible to have overlapping implementations of a trait.

Below an attempt to write a generic method that accept a `Serialize` value or an
`Arc` of a  `Serialize` value.

It leverages the `Borrow` trait and its blanket implementation for any T.

Note the use of the turbo fish syntax on the calling site of the generic method.

```
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::borrow::Borrow;
use serde::Serialize;

#[derive(Serialize, Debug)]
struct Point {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

fn myserialize<T: Borrow<I>, I: Serialize>(value: T) {
    let value = value.borrow();
    let serialized = serde_json::to_string(value).unwrap();
    println!("serialized = {}", serialized);
}


fn main() {
    let point = Point { x: 1, y: 2 };
    myserialize(point);

    let arc_point = Arc::new(Point { x: 1, y: 2 });
    myserialize::<_, Point>(arc_point);

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I realize I missed an aspect of the problem. Is there a way to wrap up `T: Borrow<I>, I: Serialize` to describe the return value of a function like `Fn() -> ???`, I will update my question to include that addition detail.

Comment: Try the signature `fn use_processor<F, O, I>(processor: F) where O: Borrow<I>, I: Serialize, F: Fn() -> O {}`

Comment: Thanks, that worked. The requirement to use the turbo fish is annoying since I have 6 type parameters (so a bunch of extra `_`s in the call), but i can live with that. Am I correct if believing that if specialization lands my original approach would work?

Comment: I've tried the latest version of your code with specialization feature but I was not able to get it working: see [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f1f035b959c513016e86ca3aa8ba9112).

Comment: I would expect that this would work as it seems obvious to me that `T` and `Inner` are the same type (i.e. some type that is `Serialize`). Maybe this is a limitation of the current implementation of specialization.

Comment: Thanks to [the answers](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/behavior-of-specialization-with-associated-types/38227)
from the rust forum the conclusion is that specialization is not suitable
for your original approach.